# AWS Athena query returning Unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a JSON file in s3 that I'm trying to run queries against using Athena. When I run my Lambda that tries to call Athena, I get this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code looks like this:

```
const athena_client = new AthenaClient({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });

const sql = `SELECT * FROM customer_data`

const params = {
            QueryString: sql,
            WorkGroup: 'customer-data-workgroup-prod'
        };

const command = new StartQueryExecutionCommand(params);

console.log("command", command)

try {
        const data = await client.send(command);
        console.log("data response: ", data)
  } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
  }
```

In s3, I have a file called movies.json, that just pulls from this test API - https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies

My Glue Table Cloudformation template looks like this:

```
  Type: AWS::Glue::Table
  Properties:
    CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
    DatabaseName: !Ref GlueDatabase
    TableInput:
      Name: customer_data
      StorageDescriptor:
        Columns:
          - Name: createdAt
            Type: timestamp
          - Name: fullJson  
            Type: string
          - Name: data  
            Type: string  
          - Name: title
            Type: string                
        Location: 's3://customer-data-bucket-prod/'
        InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat
        OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
        SerdeInfo:
          SerializationLibrary: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
      Parameters: {'classification': 'json'}
      TableType: "EXTERNAL_TABLE"
```

JSON:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 10,
  "total": 2770,
  "total_pages": 277,
  "data": [
    {
      "Title": "Waterworld",
      "Year": 1995,
      "imdbID": "tt0114898"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Waterworld",
      "Year": 1995,
      "imdbID": "tt0189200"
    },
    {
      "Title": "The Making of 'Waterworld'",
      "Year": 1995,
      "imdbID": "tt2670548"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Waterworld 4: History of the Islands",
      "Year": 1997,
      "imdbID": "tt0161077"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Waterworld",
      "Year": 1997,
      "imdbID": "tt0455840"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Waterworld",
      "Year": 1997,
      "imdbID": "tt0390617"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Swordquest: Waterworld",
      "Year": 1983,
      "imdbID": "tt2761086"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Behind the Scenes of the Most Fascinating Waterworld on Earth: The Great Backwaters, Kerala.",
      "Year": 2014,
      "imdbID": "tt5847056"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Louise's Waterworld",
      "Year": 1997,
      "imdbID": "tt0298417"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Waterworld",
      "Year": 2001,
      "imdbID": "tt0381702"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the content of movies.json as well?

Comment: @isc i have added the json

Comment: But the JSON doesn't match with your table column definition?

Comment: @isc so those columns have to match exactly my JSON structure? what if I only want to store the full json that's in data?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Glue table schema to allow Athena parsing the text file correctly.

```json
"Columns": [
    {
        "Name": "page",
        "Type": "int"
    },
    {
        "Name": "per_page",
        "Type": "int"
    },
    {
        "Name": "total",
        "Type": "int"
    },
    {
        "Name": "total_pages",
        "Type": "int"
    },
    {
        "Name": "data",
        "Type": "array<struct<Title:string,Year:int,imdbID:string>>"
    }
]
```

```json
"InputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat",
"OutputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat",
```

```json
"SerdeInfo": {
    "SerializationLibrary": "org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe",
    "Parameters": {
        "paths": "data,page,per_page,total,total_pages"
    }
}
```

In Athena,

```sql
SELECT data FROM customer_data;
```

will return all movies in an array

```
[{title=Waterworld, year=1995, imdbid=tt0114898}, {title=Waterworld, year=1995, imdbid=tt0189200}, {title=The Making of 'Waterworld', year=1995, imdbid=tt2670548}, {title=Waterworld 4: History of the Islands, year=1997, imdbid=tt0161077}, {title=Waterworld, year=1997, imdbid=tt0455840}, {title=Waterworld, year=1997, imdbid=tt0390617}, {title=Swordquest: Waterworld, year=1983, imdbid=tt2761086}, {title=Behind the Scenes of the Most Fascinating Waterworld on Earth: The Great Backwaters, Kerala., year=2014, imdbid=tt5847056}, {title=Louise's Waterworld, year=1997, imdbid=tt0298417}, {title=Waterworld, year=2001, imdbid=tt0381702}]
```

If you want a regular table, create a view based on this query

```sql
WITH w AS
  (SELECT DATA
   FROM customer_data)
SELECT movie.title,
       movie.year,
       movie.imdbid
FROM w,
     UNNEST (DATA) t(movie);
```

which gives you the result

```
#   title   year    imdbid
1   Waterworld  1995    tt0114898
2   Waterworld  1995    tt0189200
3   The Making of 'Waterworld'  1995    tt2670548
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Isc also mentioned, you need to define the columns as described in the json data.

Glue Table definition expects the column to be present in the data.Glue crawler crawls the data from external location using the Serde configuration and maps the data in the specified columns.
Hence you need to ensure that right schema is defined. Based on that, it crawls.

Your cloudformation template `Glue::Table` should look like this:

```
 Type: AWS::Glue::Table
  Properties:
    CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
    DatabaseName: !Ref GlueDatabase
    TableInput:
      Name: customer_data
      StorageDescriptor:
        Columns:
          - Name: page
            Type: int
          - Name: per_page  
            Type: int
          - Name: total  
            Type: int  
          - Name: total_pages
            Type: int     
          - Name: data
            Type: array<struct<Title:string,Year:int,imdbID:string>>           
        Location: 's3://customer-data-bucket-prod/'
        InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
        OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
        SerdeInfo:
          SerializationLibrary: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
      Parameters: {'classification': 'json'}
      TableType: "EXTERNAL_TABLE"
```

In case, if you want to use certain keys from the data, just define those in the `Columns`, Glue crawler ignores rest of the keys while crawling.

Since it is complex data type, you can flatten the arrays with `UNNEST` functions.

Refer this for details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html

Comment: Thanks! So what if my JSON contained all those fields but I only wanted the `data` field. Can I include only that in my Columns field and remove page, per_page, total, total_pages?

Comment: Yes, you can only define `data` field in Columns and remove everything else. But be aware that it is `array of struct` datatype , you need to unnest `data` while querying.  Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html